# WebView with service worker (what are ServiceWorkerController and ServiceWorkerWebSettings?)

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I have a service worker going fine in Chrome desktop and Chrome mobile, and I can tell exactly what is happening via the amazing DevTools in Chrome desktop (monitoring Chrome mobile remotely via USB).  My service worker is based very closely on [this example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/).  The page reloads fine without a network connection, and from the Network tab of DevTools I can confirm that resources are being cached and served by the service worker as expected.

But I am also loading the same page in a WebView and I'm struggling to determine whether the service worker is actually registering properly and operating as it should.  I can't see a way of debugging this in the same way as you can with DevTools in Chrome desktop/mobile.

What is certain is that the page doesn't reload without a connection when it is in the WebView, so some resources aren't being cached.  This is despite the fact that service workers [seem to be supported in WebView](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2015/03/android-webview-update.html).

Looking around the place for possible steps or settings I might be missing to get it working as it does in Chrome, I came across [ServiceWorkerController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerController.html) and [ServiceWorkerWebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerWebSettings.html), but cannot find any documentation or examples for these (other than the basic docs linked).  A search on StackOverflow for these terms gives zero results.

Is there a working example somewhere of a WebView that loads a page with attached service workers?  Any idea how to use the above two classes... are they actually necessary?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but hope it helps some anyways:

From what I can tell, the `ServiceWorkerController` is the Java implementation of ServiceWorker for WebView, which is separate from the Javascript implementation.  **The two do not seem to be tied together in any way.**

The Java implementation is a singleton which persists and affects all WebViews in an application, and its only method is to intercept requests via `shouldInterceptRequest`.  It is very similar to `WebViewClient`, the latter of which has more functionality and only affects the WebViews it is attached to (via `setWebViewClient`).

The [link](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2015/03/android-webview-update.html) you posted does seem to indicate that WebViews do support the Javascript version of ServiceWorker.  Did you by any chance miss enabling Javascript through `WebSettings.setJavascriptEnabled`?  Also, ensure that you are targeting minimum SDK version 21 as ServiceWorkers are only enabled in Android 5.0 and higher.  I am interested to know if you or anyone has managed to get a Javascript ServiceWorker functioning inside a WebView as well.