# Cache a Progressive Web App inside a WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, webview, android-webview

I've got a Progressive web app and packaged inside an android WebView.
I'd like it to work offline. How do I access the cache/service worker and make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple - use the ServiceWorkerController instance. Although it only works on Android N and up so make sure to tell your users to install your site as a PWA for these users.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerController

Comment: Thanks for the link, but how do I use the instance specifically? I'm not really sure about that, the docs don't really tell me how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773104/webview-with-service-worker-what-are-serviceworkercontroller-and-serviceworkerw shows an example and explains how it works so that should work fine for you.